# LINQ and PagedList how to orderby

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, pagedlist

i have the following table:

```
id   serialcode    timestamp
1       0001       01/02/2015
2       0001       02/02/2015
3       0001       03/02/2015
4       0002       03/02/2015
```

In linq i have got the max id for a grouped serialcode and ordered the result by descending timestamp.
So i have:

```
var list = db.mytable.GroupBy(x => x.serialcode).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);
```

I get the following rows:

```
id   serialcode    timestamp
3       0001       03/02/2015
4       0002       03/02/2015
```

Now i want filter the rows, for example, by serialcode and use the mvc pagedlist to paging the results.
I have tried:

```
var list = db.mytable.GroupBy(x => x.serialcode).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault());

list = list.Where(x => x.serialcode == myserialcode);

list.OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);
....
....
return View(list.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

But i have the following error: "The method Skip is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The methos 'OrderBy' must be called before the methos 'Skip'

What's the problem? I have ordered the result set!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to assign

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign result of `list.OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);` to `list` object.

```
 list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.timestamp);
```

`OrderByDescending` returns `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>`

Look at Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx).